# Arduino UNO and PCA9685 - Problem with external power supply

Tags: arduino-uno, power, servo, adafruit

I am totally desperate and hope you can help me.
I've been building a project for a while where I have to control several **servos**. For this I bought some **MG996R** [servos](https://www.electronicoscaldas.com/datasheet/MG996R_Tower-Pro.pdf) and a  [**PCA9685** 16-Channel Servo
Driver](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver.pdf) board. Furthermore, I bought a suitable **power supply** (DV 5V - max 3A).

First, I connected my controller and the board as follows and attached the power supply at the intended place:
[image]

Everything **worked** as desired and I could control e.g. one servo with this example script.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver myServos = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

#define SERVOMIN  150
#define SERVOMAX  600

uint8_t servonum = 0;
uint8_t numberOfServos =  1;

void setup() {
  myServos.begin();
  myServos.setPWMFreq(60);
  delay(10);
}

void loop() {
  myServos.setPWM(0, 0, 500);
  delay(1000);
  myServos.setPWM(0, 0, 300);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Then I tried something and reconnected a few cables while the power supply was still on (my bad) - after that **no servo moved** with the **original setup** (see picture above). After that I tried to find the broken part but couldn't find any - so I bought a **new Arduino, PCA board and power supply** to try and find the error - unfortunately **without** success.

Then I found out by chance that the servos move again when I connect the ground of the external power supply to the Arduino and plug the positive pole of the power supply to the **V+** with the PCA9685. That is,
[image]

I ordered a  pack of three **new** PCA9685s and again same problem - the servos no longer move when using the designated place for the power supply on the PCA9685 board - what is going on? Can anyone explain this and help me where the problem is?

Comment: measure voltage at arduino

Comment: what are your thoughts? what voltage should I measure?

Comment: power for arduino as you run motors, in each the working and failing configurations.  there are only 4 or 5 leads, at least one of which is ground so you could just measure everything one at a time and see the difference.